# substr doesn't work after using strip_tags

Tags: php, html

I want to remove all tags before showing them on preview mode (just some text).

I have this code:

```
$text = strip_tags($item['content']);
echo substr($text,0,13);
```

here is my `$item['content']` is something like this

```
 &lt;div class=&quot;note note-success&quot;&gt;
                                    &lt;p&gt;
                                         Font Awesome gives you scalable
 vector icons that can instantly be customized — size, color, drop 
shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of CSS. The 
complete set of 439 icons in Font Awesome 4.1.0
                                    &lt;/p&gt;
                                     For more info check out: &lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/&quot;&gt;http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/&lt;/a&gt;
                                &lt;/div&gt;
```

The problem is that when I use `substr` it doesn't show anything, but when I use normal `echo`, it shows the content of the variable that was stripped before.

Does `strip_tags` not give string output?

Comment: What is the value of `$item['content']` ??

Comment: When you apply `strip_tags` on an *average* HTML document, you'll get heaps of leading whitespace. Which is likely what your `substr` slices out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove whitespaces before outputting your substring:
   <s>`$new = str_replace(' ','',$text);`</s> (Use `trim` instead as *@mario.klump* said)

```
$text = strip_tags($item['content']);
$new = trim($text);
echo substr($new,0,13);
```

Comment: it works, but now my preview text doesn't has space :D

Comment: maybe you could replace spaces with "_" then strip tags, then remove spaces and convert "_" back to spaces... what does your string look like? (its contents)

Comment: Use `$new = trim($text);` instead of `$new = str_replace(' ','',$text);`.

Comment: @mario.klump I already proposed an edit and is currently under review.

Comment: thanks @mario.klump, i edited my answer to be correct. i didn't know about that function

Comment: @Minzkraut you're usage of trim function is wrong. Please see my previous edit before you applied your edit.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag i copied it from the comments but it should now be correct!?

Answer (score 1):

strip_tags() function works only when following type of html text. what you are doing is convert html encoded text so, it will not be parse.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

For your example you can use like this:

```
$text = htmlentities($item['content']);
echo substr(html_entity_decode($text),0,13); or
echo substr($text,0,13);
```